# Syntax for Vagrant provisioner cleanup tasks?

Tags: vagrant

How can I define a cleanup task in my Vagrantfile?

Vagrant's release notes for 1.3.0 mentioned a provisioner cleanup option was added but there doesn't seem to be any documentation yet and I've had no luck trying to figure out the syntax. The most relevant source file appears to [lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provisioner_cleanup.rb](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provisioner_cleanup.rb)

> **1.3.0 (September 5, 2013)**
>   Provisioners can now define "cleanup" tasks that are executed on vagrant destroy. [GH-1302]

Answer (score 6):

Here is the relevant commit:

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/commit/d4c7e2011018798b642c8bb401d61a401bfda46f

Basically, cleanup tasks must be defined by provisioner plugins. Currently, altough not documented, only the **chef_client** plugin implements this, and cleanup can be activated with the following configuration options:

```
config.vm.provision "chef_client" do |chef|
  chef.delete_client = true
  chef.delete_node   = true
end
```

If instead your goal is to define a custom task that runs on the host before and/or a command, you could use this plugin (sorry for self-referencing):

https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers

Comment: Is this still the current status? I want to execute a shell script **on the VM** before destroy.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the `run_remote` command of you vagrant-triggers plugin which fits my needs. Thank you for this amazing plugin :)